# How to create local push notification using react-native-push-notification

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

I am developing an android app using react-native, i want to use local push notification for that, like whenever i click on button, push notification should create. how can i do this?
someone please suggest me something.

Comment: You can use [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) or [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) for local push notifications as well as remote notifications.

Comment: Thank you @Hariks but i am not understanding how to use the code. where i should call the fuctions.

Comment: in 'usage' they have given some code that i am not understanding, where to write that code?

Comment: React native part or the native part where you add the package?

Comment: react-native part

Comment: Which module are you using fcm or the other one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139135/discussion-between-hariks-and-prasanna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this with **react-native-push-notification**

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

scheduleNotfication() { 
 PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({ 
 message: "My Notification Message", // message 
 date: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000)) // your required time 
 }); 
}
```

**Button**

```
<Button title="title of button" onPress ={this.scheduleNotfication() } > 
<Text>show</Text> 
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
 TouchableHighlight
 } from 'react-native';

import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

export default class pn extends Component {
  scheduleNotfication() { 
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({ 
message: "My Notification Message", // message 
date: new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000)) // your required time 
}); 
}
  render() {
    return (
      <View>


<TouchableHighlight onPress ={this.scheduleNotfication.bind(this) } >
<Text>show</Text> 
</TouchableHighlight>

      </View>
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('pn', () => pn);
```

This is working perfect and getting local Push Notification for certain time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

[react-native-notifications](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications)

It helps you in local as well as a remote push notification.

1.Remote (push) notifications

2.Local notifications

3.Background/Managed notifications (notifications that can be cleared from the server, like Facebook messenger and Whatsapp web)

4.PushKit API (for VoIP and other background messages)

5.Interactive notifications (allows you to provide additional functionality to your users outside of your application such as action buttons)

Code snippets -->

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
 TouchableHighlight
 } from 'react-native';


import {NotificationsAndroid} from 'react-native-notifications';

export default class pushLocalNotification extends Component {
  get_Local_Notfication() { 
    NotificationsAndroid.localNotification({
      title: "Local notification",
      body: "This notification was generated by the app!",
      extra: "data"
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>    
           <TouchableHighlight onPress =
                    {this.get_Local_Notfication.bind(this) } >
              <Text>show</Text> 
           </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('pushLocalNotification', () => 
    pushLocalNotification);
```

This is working perfectly for me.